# Linux Shell Curl Command

Tags: bash

I have a problem with using the curl command: I have to download a file from a site that is of `"www.example.com:8000/get.php?username=xxxx&password=xxxx"` form.

Now what happens is this: If I open the link from the browser, if that file exists, part of the automatic download, but if the link is not correct, nothing happens and the displayed page is white.
My problem is that by using the command
`curl -o file.txt "www.example.com:8000/get.php?username=xxxx&password=xxxx"`, the file is generated to me is if the link is correct, by downloading the file correctly, is that the link is not right, generating the 0 byte .txt file.

How can I do that, if not corrected the link (and therefore there is no file to download), no file is generated to me?

Comment: Check the size afterward, and if it's zero then remove the file? Can be handled automatically by a simple wrapper script.

Comment: Use `[ ! -s file.txt ]` to check if it is empty